# Generating a new Google service account credential P12 key greater than 1024 bits

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I've got an existing service account and the P12 key that was generated at the time has a key length of 1024 bits. We've used this in production for a couple of years.

We've now got a requirement (imposed by the System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler in the  https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt/ package) to sign JWTs using a key with a minimum key length of 2048 bits.

If I create a new service account in the Google Developers Console and generate a P12 key it's got a key length of 2048 bits - all good. However, if I 'Generate new P12 key' for my existing service account the new key has a key length of only 1024 bits (just like the existing one).

I need a way to create a new P12 key for my existing service account that has a 2048 bit key length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answers is it is currently not possible to do without creating a new client ID. This restriction may be relaxed at some point, but for the near future you'd need to create a new client to move to 2048 bit keys.